# Winforms - MVP Pattern: Using static ApplicationController to coordinate application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, simple-injector

**Background**

I'm building a two-tiered C# .net application:

1. Tier 1: Winforms client application using the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) design pattern.
2. Tier 2: WebAPI RESTful service sitting on top of Entity Framework and SQL Server.

Currently, I have questions relating to the overall architecture of the Winforms client application. I'm new to programming (about a year) but I've made good progress with this application. I want to step back and re-evaluate my current approach to check that I'm generally heading in the right direction.

**Application Domain**

The Winforms application is a fairly simple security personnel tracking application. The main view (Form) is the focus of the application, and has different sections which group content into functional areas (e.g. a section for tracking personnel schedules, a section for tracking who is assigned where, etc.). A menu on the side of the application launches secondary views (e.g. history, statistics, contacts, etc.). The idea is that the app could be used by a security office to organize daily operations and then keep a detailed history of everything in a database for reporting on in the future.

**Technical Details**

As mentioned, the Winforms client is built using the MVP pattern (passive view), focusing on using dependency injection as much as possible (via SimpleInjector IoC container). Each view (form) is paired up with a single presenter. The views implement interfaces, allowing the presenter to control the view (regardless of the concrete implementation). The view raises events for the presenter to subscribe to. Currently, presenters are not allowed to directly communicate to another presenter.

An application controller is used to coordinate the application. This is the area of my application architecture where I'm the most shakey (hence the post title). The application controller is currently used to:

1. Open new views (forms) and manage open forms.
2. Facilitate communication between application components via an event aggregator. One presenter publishes an event and any number of presenter can subscribe to that event.
3. Host session information (i.e. security context/logon, config data, etc.)

The IoC container is registered into the application controller at application start-up. This allows the application controller, for example, to create a presenter from the container, and then have all subsequent dependencies (view, services, etc.) to be automatically handled by the container.

**Question**

In order to make the Application Controller accessible to all presenters, I have created the controller as a static class.

```
public static class ApplicationController
{
    private static Session _session;
    private static INavigationWorkflow _workflow;
    private static EventAggregator _aggregator;

    #region Registrations

    public static void RegisterSession(Session session) {}

    public static void RegisterWorkflow(INavigationWorkflow workflow) {}

    public static void RegisterAggregator(EventAggregator aggregator) {}

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public static Session Session
    {
        get { return _session; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation

    public static void NavigateToView(Constants.View view) {}

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public static Subscription<TMessageType> Subscribe<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType> action) {}

    public static void Publish<TMessageType>(TMessageType message) {}

    public static void Unsubscribe<TMessageType>(Subscription<TMessageType> subscription) {}

    #endregion
}
```

Is this considered an acceptable practice to make a static class like this? I mean, it certainly works. It just feels... off? Are there any other holes that you can see in my architecture based on what I have described?

-

** **EDIT** **

This edit is made in response to Ric .Net’s answer posted below.

I have read through all of your suggestions. As I am committed to utilizing dependency injection to the fullest extent I can, I’m onboard with all of your suggestions. That was my plan from the beginning, but when I ran into things I didn’t understand how to accomplish via injection, I turned to the global static controller class to solve my problems (A god class it is becoming, indeed. Yikes!). Some of those questions still exist:

**Event Aggregator**

The defining line here is what should be considered optional, I think. I’ll provide a bit more context about my app before outlining my problem. Using web terminology, my main form generally acts like a [layout view](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc), hosting navigation controls and a notification section in the left menu,  and partial views being hosted in the center. Coming back to winforms terminology, the partial views are just custom made UserControls that I treat like views, and each of them are paired up with their own presenter. I have 6 of these partial views hosted on my main form, and they serve as the meat and potatoes of the application.

As an example, one partial view lists available security guards and another lists potential patrol areas. In a typical use case, a user would drag an available security guard from the available list to one of the potential patrol areas, effectively becoming assigned to that area. The patrol area view would then update to show the assigned security guard and the guard would be removed from the available list view. Utilizing drag-and-drop events, I can handle this interaction.

My questions come when I need to handle other types of interactivity between the various partial views. For example, double clicking on guard that is assigned to a location (as seen in one partial view) could highlight that guard’s name on another partial view showing all personnel schedules, or bring up employee details/history on another partial view. I could see the graph/matrix of what partial views are interested in events occurring in other partial views as becoming quite complex, and I’m not sure how to handle that via injection. With 6 partial views, I wouldn’t want to inject the other 5 partial views/presenters into each one. I was planning on accomplishing this via the event aggregator. Another example I could think of is needing to update data on a separate view (its own form) based off an event that occurs on one of the partial views on the main form.

**Session & Form Opener**

I really like your thoughts here. I’m going to take these ideas and run with them, and see where I end up!

**Security**

What are your thoughts on controlling user access to certain functionality based on what type of account they have? The recommendations I’ve been reading online say that security could be implemented by modifying the views based on their account type. The thought being, if a user can’t interact with a UI element to kick off a certain task, then the presenter will never be asked to perform that task. I’m curious if you inject the WindowsUserContext into each presenter and do additional checks, especially for http service bound requests?

I haven’t done too much development on the service side of things yet, but for http service bound requests, I imagine you need to send security information along with each request so that the service can authenticate the request. My plan was to inject the WindowsUserContext directly into the winforms service agents that end up making the service requests (i.e. the security validation would not be coming from the presenter). In that case, the service agents could potentially do a last minute security check before sending off a request.

Comment: I will try to answer your question tomorrow. Thanks for taking the time to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A static class is of course handy in some cases but there are a lot of downsides to this approach.

- The tend to grow into something like a God class. You already see this happening. So this class violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- A static class cannot have dependencies and therefore it needs to use the [Service Locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) to get it's dependencies. This is not a problem perse if you consider this class to be part of the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), but nevertheless, this often heads the wrong way.

In the supplied code I see three responsibilities of this class.

1. EventAggregator
2. What you call `Session` information
3. A service to open other views

Some feedback on this three parts:

**EventAggregator**

Although this is a widely used pattern and sometimes it can be very powerful I myself am not fond of this pattern. I see this pattern as something that provides `optional runtime data` where in most cases this runtime data is not optional at all. In other words, only use this pattern for truly optional data. For everything that is not really optional, use hard dependencies, using constructor injection.

The ones that need the information in that case depend upon `IEventListener<TMessage>`. The one that publish the event, depend upon `IEventPublisher<TMessage>`.

```
public interface IEventListener<TMessage> 
{
    event Action<TMessage> MessageReceived;
}

public interface IEventPublisher<TMessage> 
{
    void Publish(TMessage message);
}

public class EventPublisher<TMessage> : IEventPublisher<TMessage> 
{
    private readonly EventOrchestrator<TMessage> orchestrator;

    public EventPublisher(EventOrchestrator<TMessage> orchestrator) 
    {
        this.orchestrator = orchestrator;
    }

    public void Publish(TMessage message) => this.orchestrator.Publish(message);
}

public class EventListener<TMessage> : IEventListener<TMessage> 
{
    private readonly EventOrchestrator<TMessage> orchestrator;

    public EventListener(EventOrchestrator<TMessage> orchestrator) 
    {
        this.orchestrator = orchestrator;
    }

    public event Action<TMessage> MessageReceived 
    {
        add { orchestrator.MessageReceived += value; }
        remove { orchestrator.MessageReceived -= value; }
    }
}

public class EventOrchestrator<TMessage> 
{
    public void Publish(TMessage message) => this.MessageReceived(message);
    public event Action<TMessage> MessageReceived = (e) => { };
}
```

To be able to guarantee events are stored in one single location, we extract that storage (the `event`) into its own class, the `EventOrchestrator`.

The registration is as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IEventListener<>), typeof(EventListener<>));
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IEventPublisher<>), typeof(EventPublisher<>));
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(EventOrchestrator<>), typeof(EventOrchestrator<>));
```

Usage is trivial:

```
public class SomeView
{
    private readonly IEventPublisher<GuardChanged> eventPublisher;

    public SomeView(IEventPublisher<GuardChanged> eventPublisher)
    {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    public void GuardSelectionClick(Guard guard)
    {
        this.eventPublisher.Publish(new GuardChanged(guard));
    }
    // other code..
}

public class SomeOtherView
{
    public SomeOtherView(IEventListener<GuardChanged> eventListener)
    {
        eventListener.MessageReceived += this.GuardChanged;
    }

    private void GuardChanged(GuardChanged changedGuard)
    {
        this.CurrentGuard = changedGuard.SelectedGuard;
    }
    // other code..
}
```

If another view will receive a lot of events you could always wrap all IEventListeners of that View in a specific `EventHandlerForViewX` class which get all important `IEventListener<>` injected.

**Session**

In the question you define several `ambient context` variables as `Session` information. Exposing this kind of information through a static class promotes tight coupling to this static class and thus makes it more difficult to unit test parts of your application. IMO all information provided by `Session` is static (in the sense that it doesn't change throughout the lifetime of the application) data that could just as easily be injected into those parts that actually need this data. So `Session` should completely be removed from the static class. Some examples how to solve this in a SOLID manner:

*Configuration values*

The composition root is in charge of reading all information from the configuration source (e.g. your app.config file). This information can there be stored in a POCO class crafted for its usage.

```
public interface IMailSettings
{
    string MailAddress { get; }
    string DefaultMailSubject { get; }
}

public interface IFtpInformation
{
    int FtpPort { get; }
}

public interface IFlowerServiceInformation
{
    string FlowerShopAddress { get; }
}

public class ConfigValues :
    IMailSettings, IFtpInformation, IFlowerServiceInformation
{
    public string MailAddress { get; set; }
    public string DefaultMailSubject { get; set; }

    public int FtpPort { get; set; }

    public string FlowerShopAddress { get; set; }
}
// Register as
public static void RegisterConfig(this Container container)
{
    var config = new ConfigValues
    {
        MailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAddress"],
        DefaultMailSubject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultMailSubject"],
        FtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPort"]),
        FlowerShopAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FlowerShopAddress"],
    };

    var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<ConfigValues>(() => 
                                config, container);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(IMailSettings),registration);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(IFtpInformation),registration);
    container.AddRegistration(typeof(IFlowerServiceInformation),registration);
}
```

And where you need some specific information, e.g. information to send an email you can just put `IMailSettings` in the constructor of the type needing the information.

This will also give you the possibility to test a component using different config values, which would be harder to do if all config information had to come from the static `ApplicationController`.

For security information, e.g. the logged on User the same pattern can be used. Define an `IUserContext` abstraction, create a WindowsUserContext implementation and fill this with the logged on user in the composition root. Because the component now depends on `IUserContext` instead of getting the user at runtime from the static class, the same component could also be used in an MVC application, where you would replace the `WindowsUserContext` with an `HttpUserContext` implementation.

**Opening other forms**

This is actually the hard part. I normally also use some big static class with all kinds of methods to open other forms. I don't expose the `IFormOpener` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417654/winforms-how-to-register-forms-with-ioc-container/38421425#38421425) to my other forms, because they only need to know, what to do, not which form does that task for them. So my static class exposes this kinds of methods:

```
public SomeReturnValue OpenCustomerForEdit(Customer customer)
{ 
     var form = MyStaticClass.FormOpener.GetForm<EditCustomerForm>();
     form.SetCustomer(customer);
     var result = MyStaticClass.FormOpener.ShowModalForm(form);
     return (SomeReturnValue) result;
}
```

However....

I'm not at all happy with this approach, because over time this class grows and grows. With WPF I use another mechanism, which I think could also be used with WinForms. This approach is based on a message based architecture described in [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) awesome blogposts. Although at first the information looks as it is not at all related, it is the message based concept that let these patterns rock!

All my WPF windows implement an open generic interface, e.g. IEditView. And if some view needs to edit a customer, it just get's this IEditView injected. A decorator is used to actually show the view in pretty much the same way as the forementioned `FormOpener` does it. In this case I make use of a specific Simple Injector feature, called [decorate factory decorator](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators-with-func-t-decoratee-factories), which you can use to create forms whenever it is needed, just as the `FormOpener` used the container directly to create forms whenever it needs to.

So I did not really test this, so there could be some pitfalls with WinForms, but this code seems to work on a first and single run..

```
public class EditViewShowerDecorator<TEntity> : IEditView<TEntity>
{
    private readonly Func<IEditView<TEntity>> viewCreator;

    public EditViewShowerDecorator(Func<IEditView<TEntity>> viewCreator)
    {
        this.viewCreator = viewCreator;
    }

    public void EditEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        // get view from container
        var view = this.viewCreator.Invoke();
        // initview with information
        view.EditEntity(entity);
        using (var form = (Form)view)
        {
            // show the view
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

The forms and decorator should be registered as:

```
container.Register(typeof(IEditView<>), new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IEditView<>), typeof(EditViewShowerDecorator<>), 
                             Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

**Security**

The `IUserContext` must the base for all security.

For the userinterface I normally hide all controls/buttons that a certain userrole doesn't have access to. The best place is to perform this in the `Load` event.

Because I use the command/handler pattern as described [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for my all actions external of my forms/views I use a decorator to check if a user has permission to perform this certain command (or query).

I would advise you to read this post a few times until you really get the hang of it. Once you get familiar with this pattern you won't do anything else!

If you have any questions about these patterns and how to apply a (permission)decorator, add a comment!

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer @Ric ! I can't thank you enough for taking the time to review my background/questions and providing such detailed, thoughtful answers. I have edited my initial post to add some addition questions. Don't feel pressured to answer them as you have already helped immensely!

Comment: @Andrew see my updated answer. I added the information how to go about Events. This will probably partially answer your extra question. I added something about security, but the details deserve a answer on its own.

Comment: Again @Ric thank you so much. I have a pretty solid static event event aggregator that I was using, but your method for injecting the event dependencies is just awesome. I will be looking to implement that shortly. As for opening other forms, I modified my existing form opener to incorporate some elements of your FormOpener as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417654/winforms-how-to-register-forms-with-ioc-container/38421425#38421425). My plan was just to allow all forms to access the form opener direct, and coordinate opening subsequent forms.

Comment: I know a form doesn't need to know what form to use to accomplish a task, but given the simplicity of my application, I don't see any major problems giving my forms direct FormOpener access. Humoursly, google allowed me to stumble on Steven's blog months ago, where I read about his command architecture and first discovered SimpleInjector. Initially, I was only planning to use the command architecture for my Web service, but not my WinForms app. Reflecting on that now, I see that I definitely should. Once I get some experience with the pattern, then I'll revisit your form opener pattern.

Comment: Lastly, I haven't implemented security at all yet, so I have a lot to learn. Over the next while I will  dive in and do some research first. Hopefully when I inevitably run into issues, I will be able to get your attention (and if you can spare the time)! I greatly appreciate all your help!