# Singleton for constructor with parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `winform` constructor with parameter:

```
    public SnippingTool(Bitmap screenShot)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackgroundImage = screenShot;
            ...
        }
```

I need only one instance of my `winform` while app is running, so I decided to use singleton pattern.

I found this construction (it's not suitable because of parameter in my class constructor):

```
    private static SnippingTool instance;

    public static SnippingTool GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new SnippingTool();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

How can I pass parameter through singleton?

Comment: Change the property call to a method call and make the method callable with a parameter?

Comment: I'd make a Bitmap property in the singleton and just set it once, throw an error if it hasn't been set.

Comment: Why you have a property `IsDisposed`?

Comment: Why not create it once and when you need it make sure to pass it along as a parameter/similar? No need to implement singleton IMO. (This is usually called dependency injection)

Comment: The answer to this depends on where you will get `screenShot` from - is it available only at the time that you call `GetInstance`? Or is it available before then?

Comment: Instead of singleton of the type instance itself, consider to store it somewhere else, e.g. as `App.MainForm` property. Now you can construct it explicitly somewhere during application startup. Note: keep instance `null` and allow software to crash (with logging of course) to catch cases when something is trying to access instance *before* it is initialized.

Comment: Thus, answers present here is very simple, I tend to use inversion of control even for winforms. Their lifetime can very frustrating. Also, disposing winforms is a pain, so I recommend you to look at solution present here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417654/winforms-how-to-register-forms-with-ioc-container

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks, there is no need for `IsDisposed`

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks, I've complemented my question

Answer (score 1):

If the Bitmap is different every time, and you definitely want only one `SnippingTool`, then maybe the Bitmap should not even have an instance variable of the tool, and then certainly the Bitmap has no place in the Constructor.

Instead make the Bitmap a parameter of the main 'operating' method(s) that you are calling on the `SnippingTool` instance.

Or if you need the `SnippingTool` to have a Bitmap as 'state' (because it is a Form, and it needs to show & edit the image), then create methods such as `SetImage(Bitmap b)`, `ClearImage()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SnippingTool instance;

public static SnippingTool GetInstance(Bitmap screenShot)
{
        if (instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
        {
           instance = new SnippingTool(); 
        }
        instance.SetBitmap(screenShot); // if you need otherwise pass it to constructor
        return instance;
}
```

Comment: I guess, you need a semicolon after `instance.SetBitmap(screenShot)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a method instead of property.

```
private static SnippingTool _instance;

public static SnippingTool GetInstance(Bitmap screen)
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null || _instance.IsDisposed)
        {
            _instance = new SnippingTool(screen);
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you go through this approach, make SnippingTool(Bitmap) constructor private :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 private static SnippingTool instance;

 private SnippingTool (var par){
   ....
 }

 public SnippingTool createSingleton(var par){
   if instance != null 
               return instance;
   else 
      return new SnippingTool(par);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this `SnippingTool` can be used only with one `BitMap` instance there is no reason to always pass one to the singleton property/method. That would at least be confusing because the caller would think that he would get a tool for this bitmap. The method should throw an exception if you pass a different instance. But does this make sense at all, not much in my opinion.

So i would go this way, implement a `SetScreenshot` or `SetInstance` method, f.e.:

```
public class SnippingTool
{
    private SnippingTool(Bitmap screenShot)
    {
        this.ScreenShot = screenShot;
    }

    private static SnippingTool instance;

    public static void SetScreenshot(Bitmap screenShot)
    {
        if (instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
        {
            instance = new SnippingTool(screenShot);
        }
        else
        {
            // now your logic, is it allowed then overwrite the screenShot, otherwise:
            throw new ArgumentException("It's not allowed to change the screenShot for this SnippingTool", nameof(screenShot));
        }
    }

    public static SnippingTool GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new Exception("The SnippingTool needs a screenShot first, use first " + nameof(SetScreenshot));
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap ScreenShot { get; }

    // ...
}
```